# Why does my fwrite command only run once?

Tags: c++, file, fwrite

I'm using `fwrite` to store the values of a QVector called `rawData`.

Here is my code:

```
unsigend short* ptr = rawdata();    

FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen("arrayValues.txt", "a");
fwrite(ptr, sizeof(unsigned short), sizeof(rawData), pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

The program above "works" meaning I was able to write to a file and when I open the file with a hex editor I can see stuff in there. However, it only write the values for one frame and then stops even though the program is calling that method over and over again.

Even stranger, if I close the program and run it again, it will open the file (which already has values from the last run inside it) and append a new set of values to the end. So I know that I'm opening the file in append mode.

Comment: Can you show how the code segment is called more than once?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Problem is likely in code not shown.

Comment: What is `rawdata()` and `rawData`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's in a method called `run()` it's a lot of code so that's why I didn't include it.

Comment: @Olivier No that's where the problem is because when I used `fstream` and iterated through the vector I was able to write all the values without a problem.

Comment: @Muscampester It's a QVector.

Comment: I agree with Olivier: the problem is most likely in code not shown (and `sizeof(rawData)` is likely wrong as it is just the size of the pointer, not the size of the pointed to sequence).

Comment: You seem to write binary data into a file opened in the text mode (and with a .txt extension). This is not the immediate source of the problem, but most likely it is not what you want. `pFile = fopen("arrayValues.bin", "ab");` would be more portable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you mentioned `rawData` is a QVector, replace:

```
sizeof(rawData)
```

with

```
rawData.size()
```

If this does not work, I don't think the issue is with the code you showed us. Please provide more information/code.

Explanation: The `sizeof` operator returns the size in bytes of the type you give as its argument. In your case, it is returning the number of bytes used by type `QVector` as you are not giving it any pointer as an argument but an object of type `QVector`. The member funciton `size()` is a good way to get the number of elements for the class `QVector`.

Comment: That worked! Would you mind explaining what was wrong with what I had before?

Comment: I've added the explanation in the answer.